# Does ReSharper analyze the _references.js file for JavaScript IntelliSense?

Tags: resharper, javascript-intellisense

It seems like R# only looks at the files referenced at the top of the current file, and so is not showing IntelliSense information that would have appeared in bare-bones Visual Studio. Maybe I'm missing something, though, and it's a configuration option somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that Resharper (8.0.1 as of this answer) does not pay any attention to the _references.js file. It analyzes the project for any/all available javascript files and provides Intellisense accordingly. One important thing you lose with R# compared to VS default functionality is the ability to reference remote js files, eg:

```
///<reference path="http://whatever.com/your.js" />
```

will not work. Currently [it's a known bug with no scheduled fix.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-338722)